# glGetUniformLocation() returns -1, but Uniform still works

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have been having trouble with `glGetUniformLocation()`. I am trying to get the location of a uniform in my fragment shader, but whenever I call it, the function returns -1.

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 450
// The fragment shader acts on each pixel in a given polygon

in vec4 fragmentColor;

// color of the pixel
out vec4 color;

uniform float time;


void main(){
    color = fragmentColor + vec4(1.0 * (cos(time)+1.0) * 0.5,  
                                 1.0 * (cos(time + 2.0)+1.0) * 0.5,  
                                 1.0 * (sin(time + 1.0)+1.0) * 0.5, 0.0); // Set color

}
```

Here is where I call `glGetUniformLocation()`:

```
GLuint GLSLProgram::getUniformLocation(const std::string uniformName){

    GLuint location = glGetUniformLocation(_programID, uniformName.c_str());

    if (location = GL_INVALID_INDEX){
        std::cout << (int)location << std::endl;
        fatalError("Error: Uniform '" + uniformName + "' not found in shader!");
    }
    return location;
}
```

In my drawScreen function I wrote:

```
GLuint timeLocation = _colorProgram.getUniformLocation("time");
```

The uniform is clearly being used to calculate the color, so it should not be optimized out by the GPU.

But it gets better. If I put `layout(location = 2)` in front of `uniform float time`, I can now use `glUniform1f(2, _time)` to modify the uniform.

Does this mean `glGetUniformLocation()` is broken? or am I using it wrong?

Comment: More than likely, your code has a bug in it. But since you didn't choose to post that code, we can't really tell you what it is.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: if (location **==** GL_INVALID_INDEX)

Comment: Thank you it worked! @Zefick